# How byte addressing works?

Tags: memory, computer-architecture

I am new to computer architecture. So correct me if I am wrong.

If a memory module consists of 8 memory chips and if each chip stores 4bits per address then by applying an address to the address pin of the module I can get (8 x 4=) 32 bit from that address in the module. But byte addressing tells that every byte has an address. But here I am accessing 32bits using an address. So how is it possible?

I think if each chip stores 1bit per address then by applying an address to the module I can access 8bit or one byte.

Comment: Modern processors are optimized for the general case (e.g. fetching instructions in full words) rather than odd data byte.  Modern memory is typically byte addressable, but the hardware implementation is often for wider data.  You are confusing implementation with capability; they do not have to be identical.  Maybe a Harvard architecture computer might do it your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first, the organization of the memory on DIMMs is really quite transparent to programs and even the CPU. But... in all recent systems using commodity processors and DIMMs, the DIMMs actually implement 64-bit-wide "words" (not 32, not even on 32-bit CPUs).

Back in the day when commodity (x86) CPUs had separate address vs. data pins, if you looked at the designations on the address pins you'd find they didn't start at A0 (the least significant bit of an address), but rather at A3. So although the addresses asserted by programs do go "all the way down" to address bit 0, and after address translation the resulting physical address also goes to bit 0, the low-order three bits of physical address never make it out of the processor. The processor reads and writes RAM in 8-byte (64-bit) words, and these are always aligned on 8-byte boundaries. The same is true today, even though address and data signals are multiplexed on the bus (i.e. they use the same pins on the CPU).

Addressing of things smaller than the 8-byte words, for example

```
MOV AL, [EBX]
```

(move the byte whose address is in EBX to the low-order byte of the A-register) is all implemented within the processor and the on-chip memory cache. The memory controller fetches the 64-bit word that contains the byte you want and stores all of it in the cache. (Actually the cache is organized in "cache lines" of *64 bytes* each, so eight successive 64-bit words are read from the DIMMs into the cache, but never mind that...) This word is then put on an internal data bus in the CPU, from which the CPU accesses the byte(s) that it needs, based on the low-order three bits of the address. Or, perhaps, the interface to the cache does this - this isn't clear to me.

(Of course, if the needed word was already in the cache, there's no access to the DIMMs at all.)

Similarly for writing an individual byte, the CPU (or the cache interface) has to read the containing 8-byte word from the cache, change it according to which bytes are to be affected, and then send the resulting 8-byte word back to the cache. Eventually it gets flushed to RAM.

Comment: Actually my question is about those CPUs when there was separate address and data pins. But I cannot understand when an address on the memory module stores more than a byte is similar to byte addressing, where by a byte is stored in an particular address?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. My question refers to this point how byte addressing is implemented in 32bit or 64bit wide DIMM?

Comment: *"Back in the day when CPUs had separate address vs. data pins..."* -- That's a very inaccurate specification, especially since you also constrain your history search to modern x86, yet use the generic *"CPU"*.

Comment: @sawdust: Good point, fixed.

Comment: @Kaustav: My point is that it _isn't implemented on the memory modules_ at all. The DIMMs _only_ read and write in 64-bit-sized words, which are always (from the CPU's point of view) aligned on eight-byte boundaries. If the processor needs a single byte that's one of the bytes from (let us say) physical addresses 0x41F00 through 0x41F07 - that's an eight-byte span - the address that goes to the DIMMs is 0x83E1, which is 41f07 shifted right three bits. The low-order three bits of the addresses never get to the DIMMs at all, and don't need to. If this still isn't clear, please LMK.

Comment: @Jamie Now I can understand. But still can you please provide some materials on the topic?

Comment: I will, but I have Real Work to do today. So it will not be immediate.

Comment: @Jamie can you please provide some materials regarding the topic

Comment: The info on the address bits out of the CPU, and the fact that memory in the DIMMs is addressed in terms of 8-byte "words", 64 bits at a time, is in the Intel and AMD CPU technical specs and also in the specs on memory modules at JEDEC. Given that, it is therefore axiomatic that RAM is addressed only in 64-bit words - the interface at the edge of a DIMM simply doesn't implement anything else. Some of the stuff on the workings of the is here: https://lwn.net/Articles/252125/ , though it's somewhat old, it's still about 90% correct.

Comment: Uh, make that "the workings of the _cache_ is here" in the last sentence. (Need better flow control between brain and fingers; I keep overrunning the latters' buffers.)